# How to call previous two week same day value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, forecasting

I am trying to fetch previous week same day data and then take an average of the value ("current_demand") for today's forecast (predict).

for example:

Today is Monday, so then I want to fetch data from the last two weeks Monday's data same time or block and then take an average of the value ["current_demand"] to predict today's value.

Input Data:

```
current_demand  Date    Blockno weekday
        18839   01-06-2018  1   4
        18836   01-06-2018  2   4
        12256   02-06-2018  1   5
        12266   02-06-2018  2   5
        17957   08-06-2018  1   4
        17986   08-06-2018  2   4
        18491   09-06-2018  1   5
        18272   09-06-2018  2   5
```

Expecting result:

```
        18398   15-06-2018  1   4
```

something like that. I want to take same value, same block and same day of the previous two-week value then calculate for next value average.

I have tried some thing:

```
def forecast(DATA):
    df = DATA
    day = {0:'Monday',1:'Tuesday',2:'Wednesday',3:'Thursday',4:'Friday',5:'Saturday',6:'Sunday'}
    df.friday = day - timedelta(days=day.weekday() + 3)
    print df

forecast(DATA)
```

Please suggest me something. Thank you in advance

Comment: Something like `df.set_index('Date').resample('2W-MON').mean().dropna()`?

Answer (score 1):

I like relativedelta for this kind of job

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
(datetime.datetime.today() + relativedelta(weeks=-2)).date()
```

Output:

```
datetime.date(2018, 7, 23)
```

without the actual structure of your df it's hard to provide a solution tailored to your needs